# "For all" statements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, types, type-conversion, conditional-statements

I'm building comfort going through some Haskell toy problems and I've written the following speck of code

```
multipOf :: [a] -> (Int, a)
multipOf x = (length x, head x)
gmcompress x = (map multipOf).group $ x
```

which successfully preforms the following operation

```
gmcompress [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3] = [(4,1),(3,2),(1,3)]
```

Now I want this function to instead of telling me that an element of the set had multiplicity 1, to just leave it alone. So to give the result [(4,1),(3,2),3] instead. It be great if there were a way to say (either during or after turning the list into one of pairs) for all elements of multiplicity 1, leave as just an element; else, pair. My initial, naive, thought was to do the following.

```
multipOf :: [a] -> (Int, a)
multipOf x = if length x = 1 then head x else (length x, head x)
gmcompress x = (map multipOf).group $ x
```

BUT this doesn't work. I think because the `then` and `else` clauses have different types, and unfortunately you can't piece-wise define the (co)domain of your functions. How might I go about getting past this issue?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't (cannot) type check as-is. You could possibly change it to an ADT, but the original code is way better.

Comment: A list like `[(1,2),(3,2)]` has type `Num a => [(a,a)]`. But `[(4,1),(3,2),3]` just doesn't typecheck in haskell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't really seem to have an _answer_, other than "you can't do that in a statically typed language" (or indeed "that's the point of static types"). Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33312250/edit) if you feel you can clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you want to have such a list? Tell us how you are going to use it, and perhaps we can give you some alternatives.

Comment: You need a type encompassing both kinds of values that can be put in the list. E.g. `Either Int (Int,Int)` or a custom algebraic type. You will need to wrap both kinds of values in their related constructor.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, sure we can do this with static types — they just need to be dependent. But even in a dependently typed language I would use `Either Int (Int, Int)`.

Comment: @user3237465 Sure, you could do it with a sigma type (which I suspect would end up being isomorphic to `Either Int (Int, Int)` anyway?). But I don't think the question was really looking for that sort of answer ;)

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, [not necessarily Sigmas](http://lpaste.net/143735). Anyway, I'd just wanted to say that the question is not inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BUT this doesn't work. I think because the then and else clauses have different types, and unfortunately you can't piece-wise define the (co)domain of your functions. How might I go about getting past this issue?

Your diagnosis is right; the `then` and `else` must have the same type.  There's no "getting past this issue," strictly speaking.  Whatever solution you adopt has to use same type in both branches of the conditional.  One way would be to design a custom data type that encodes the possibilities that you want, and use that instead.  Something like this would work:

```
-- | A 'Run' of @a@ is either 'One' @a@ or 'Many' of them (with the number
-- as an argument to the 'Many' constructor).
data Run a = One a | Many Int a
```

But to tell you the truth, I don't think this would really gain you anything.  I'd stick to the `(Int, a)` encoding rather than going to this `Run` type.

Comment: Ah, yes. Forgot that lists in Haskell can't mix types.